# How to post a message once the current instance of the message has finished in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc, postmessage

I don't have enough understanding of messages in Windows applications.

I have this button handler:

```
void CChristianLifeMinistryEditorDlg::OnFilePublicTalk()
{
    CWeekendMeetingDlg dlgPublicTalk(this);

    if (m_pEntry != nullptr)
    {
        dlgPublicTalk.SetPublicTalkInfo(m_pEntry->GetPublicTalkInfo());
        dlgPublicTalk.SetCircuitVisitMode(m_iIncludeMode == kIncludeServiceTalk); // AJT v17.0.7
        // AJT v20.0.1
        dlgPublicTalk.SetSongInfo(
            CChristianLifeMinistryUtils::UseSingOutJoyfullyToJehovah(m_datFirstMonday), m_eForeignLang);
        auto iResult = dlgPublicTalk.DoModal();
        if (iResult == IDOK || iResult == to_underlying(CWeekendMeetingDlg::EndResult::PreviousDate) ||
                               iResult == to_underlying(CWeekendMeetingDlg::EndResult::NextDate))
        {
            m_pEntry->SetPublicTalkInfo(dlgPublicTalk.GetPublicTalkInfo());

            SetModified(true);
            UpdatePreview(m_iDateIndex);
            m_pHtmlPreview->Refresh2(REFRESH_COMPLETELY); // Ensure it has refreshed

            // Padlock
            // Reminder
            // Disable controls

            if (iResult == to_underlying(CWeekendMeetingDlg::EndResult::PreviousDate))
            {
                AfxMessageBox(_T("Move to previous week."));
                PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, ID_FILE_PUBLIC_TALK, 0);

                // It can't process this message until the current instance one has finished

            }
            else if (iResult == to_underlying(CWeekendMeetingDlg::EndResult::NextDate))
            {
                AfxMessageBox(_T("Move to next week."));
                PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, ID_FILE_PUBLIC_TALK, 0);

                // It can't process this message until the current instance one has finished
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have removed code (replaced with the two `AfxMessageBox` calls) but in principle I want to re-start the same event handler as if the user had clicked it on the File menu. Is it OK to use `PostMessage` when the current instance of the message has not yet terminated?

---

I have not yet tried the answer provided, but I have encountered an issue when I introduce two `PostMessage` calls:

```
void CChristianLifeMinistryEditorDlg::OnFilePublicTalk()
{
    CWeekendMeetingDlg dlgPublicTalk(this);

    if (m_pEntry != nullptr)
    {
        dlgPublicTalk.SetPublicTalkInfo(m_pEntry->GetPublicTalkInfo());
        dlgPublicTalk.SetCircuitVisitMode(m_iIncludeMode == kIncludeServiceTalk); // AJT v17.0.7
        // AJT v20.0.1
        dlgPublicTalk.SetSongInfo(
            CChristianLifeMinistryUtils::UseSingOutJoyfullyToJehovah(m_datFirstMonday), m_eForeignLang);

        // AJT v20.1.8
        dlgPublicTalk.SetPreviousNextDateButtonStates(m_btnMovePrevious.IsWindowEnabled(),
                                                      m_btnMoveNext.IsWindowEnabled());
        auto iResult = dlgPublicTalk.DoModal();
        if (iResult == IDOK || iResult == to_underlying(CWeekendMeetingDlg::EndResult::PreviousDate) ||
                               iResult == to_underlying(CWeekendMeetingDlg::EndResult::NextDate))
        {
            m_pEntry->SetPublicTalkInfo(dlgPublicTalk.GetPublicTalkInfo());

            SetModified(true);
            UpdatePreview(m_iDateIndex);
            m_pHtmlPreview->Refresh2(REFRESH_COMPLETELY); // Ensure it has refreshed

            if (iResult == to_underlying(CWeekendMeetingDlg::EndResult::PreviousDate))
            {
                PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM(IDC_MFCBUTTON_PREVIOUS_DATE, BN_CLICKED),
                    (LPARAM)m_btnMovePrevious.GetSafeHwnd());
                PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, ID_FILE_PUBLIC_TALK, 0);
            }
            else if (iResult == to_underlying(CWeekendMeetingDlg::EndResult::NextDate))
            {
                PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM(IDC_MFCBUTTON_NEXT_DATE, BN_CLICKED),
                    (LPARAM)m_btnMoveNext.GetSafeHwnd());
                PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, ID_FILE_PUBLIC_TALK, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After the actions have been performed and it re-displays the window, and I then click Cancel I get:

[image]

If I change it and directly call the button handlers, like this:

```
void CChristianLifeMinistryEditorDlg::OnFilePublicTalk()
{
    CWeekendMeetingDlg dlgPublicTalk(this);

    if (m_pEntry != nullptr)
    {
        dlgPublicTalk.SetPublicTalkInfo(m_pEntry->GetPublicTalkInfo());
        dlgPublicTalk.SetCircuitVisitMode(m_iIncludeMode == kIncludeServiceTalk); // AJT v17.0.7
        // AJT v20.0.1
        dlgPublicTalk.SetSongInfo(
            CChristianLifeMinistryUtils::UseSingOutJoyfullyToJehovah(m_datFirstMonday), m_eForeignLang);

        // AJT v20.1.8
        dlgPublicTalk.SetPreviousNextDateButtonStates(m_btnMovePrevious.IsWindowEnabled(),
                                                      m_btnMoveNext.IsWindowEnabled());
        auto iResult = dlgPublicTalk.DoModal();
        if (iResult == IDOK || iResult == to_underlying(CWeekendMeetingDlg::EndResult::PreviousDate) ||
                               iResult == to_underlying(CWeekendMeetingDlg::EndResult::NextDate))
        {
            m_pEntry->SetPublicTalkInfo(dlgPublicTalk.GetPublicTalkInfo());

            SetModified(true);
            UpdatePreview(m_iDateIndex);
            m_pHtmlPreview->Refresh2(REFRESH_COMPLETELY); // Ensure it has refreshed

            if (iResult == to_underlying(CWeekendMeetingDlg::EndResult::PreviousDate))
            {
                //PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM(IDC_MFCBUTTON_PREVIOUS_DATE, BN_CLICKED),
                //  (LPARAM)m_btnMovePrevious.GetSafeHwnd());
                OnBnClickedMfcbuttonPreviousDate();
                PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, ID_FILE_PUBLIC_TALK, 0);
            }
            else if (iResult == to_underlying(CWeekendMeetingDlg::EndResult::NextDate))
            {
                //PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM(IDC_MFCBUTTON_NEXT_DATE, BN_CLICKED),
                //  (LPARAM)m_btnMoveNext.GetSafeHwnd());
                OnBnClickedMfcbuttonNextDate();
                PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, ID_FILE_PUBLIC_TALK, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This latter approach works. I should point out that these two button handlers update a HTML file and redraw it in the web browser control (which is actually on the parent dialog).

Is it acceptable to directly call those button handlers like this?

---

Using the answer provided (thank you) this is working well:

```
void CChristianLifeMinistryEditorDlg::OnFilePublicTalk()
{
    delay_post_msg dpm{ this };
    CWeekendMeetingDlg dlgPublicTalk(this);

    if (m_pEntry != nullptr)
    {
        dlgPublicTalk.SetPublicTalkInfo(m_pEntry->GetPublicTalkInfo());
        dlgPublicTalk.SetCircuitVisitMode(m_iIncludeMode == kIncludeServiceTalk); // AJT v17.0.7
        // AJT v20.0.1
        dlgPublicTalk.SetSongInfo(
            CChristianLifeMinistryUtils::UseSingOutJoyfullyToJehovah(m_datFirstMonday), m_eForeignLang);

        // AJT v20.1.8
        dlgPublicTalk.SetPreviousNextDateButtonStates(m_btnMovePrevious.IsWindowEnabled(),
                                                      m_btnMoveNext.IsWindowEnabled());
        auto iResult = dlgPublicTalk.DoModal();
        if (iResult == IDOK || iResult == to_underlying(CWeekendMeetingDlg::EndResult::PreviousDate) ||
                               iResult == to_underlying(CWeekendMeetingDlg::EndResult::NextDate))
        {
            m_pEntry->SetPublicTalkInfo(dlgPublicTalk.GetPublicTalkInfo());

            SetModified(true);
            UpdatePreview(m_iDateIndex);
            m_pHtmlPreview->Refresh2(REFRESH_COMPLETELY); // Ensure it has refreshed

            if (iResult == to_underlying(CWeekendMeetingDlg::EndResult::PreviousDate))
            {
                //PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM(IDC_MFCBUTTON_PREVIOUS_DATE, BN_CLICKED),
                //  (LPARAM)m_btnMovePrevious.GetSafeHwnd());
                OnBnClickedMfcbuttonPreviousDate();
                //PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, ID_FILE_PUBLIC_TALK, 0);
                dpm.set_active();
            }
            else if (iResult == to_underlying(CWeekendMeetingDlg::EndResult::NextDate))
            {
                //PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM(IDC_MFCBUTTON_NEXT_DATE, BN_CLICKED),
                //  (LPARAM)m_btnMoveNext.GetSafeHwnd());
                OnBnClickedMfcbuttonNextDate();
                //PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, ID_FILE_PUBLIC_TALK, 0);
                dpm.set_active();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I had to use the two `OnBnClickedMfcbuttonPreviousDate` / `OnBnClickedMfcbuttonNextDate` button handlers directly without using `PostMessage` to simulate button clicks. I assume that is acceptable?

Comment: I think you're OK *in theory*. Messages are placed into a queue for each thread, where they're handled in the order they go in (I think). There are potentially many messages going into the thread's queue at any time. But is that what you want, or do you want to call the handler *immediately*? In the latter case, maybe just do that: call it recursively?

Comment: @AdrianMole I am happy for it to go in the queue.

Comment: Then just be sure that your handler function has finished (and returned) before it gets kicked off again by the posted message.

Comment: @AdrianMole That was my concern. How do we do that?

Comment: If you return from your handler on the next line after the `PostMessage` (which, of course, returns asynchronously), I can't see how there could be a problem.

Comment: @AdrianMole I have basically done what you suggested, by using the approach provided in the answer. The only issue I had was that for two of my additional `PostMessage` calls I had to use the event handlers directly. Otherwise it seems robust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, this is safe. `PostMessage` generates a [queued message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues#queued-messages) that doesn't get observed until the current thread gets around to calling a message-retrieval function (like `GetMessage`) again. The message loop, however, is blocked, waiting for the current message handler to return control back to it.

Unfortunately, the (main) message loop provided by MFC isn't the only code that potentially dispatches messages. Dialogs (like `MessageBox`es) fire up their own message loop, for example. As do menus, or the window resizing implementation. Lots of opportunities to revert back to the reentrancy you were trying to guard against.

A more robust solution could postpone the `PostMessage` call to just before the function returns. C++ provides all the tools required to implement this: Destructors!

```cpp
struct delay_post_msg {
    delay_post_msg(CWnd* w) : w_{ w }, active_{ false } {}
    void set_active() { active_ = true; }
    ~delay_post_msg()
    {
        if (active_) w_->PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, ID_FILE_PUBLIC_TALK, 0);
    }
private:
    CWnd* w_;
    bool active_;
};
```

You'd use it something like this:

```cpp
void CChristianLifeMinistryEditorDlg::OnFilePublicTalk()
{
    // Objects are destroyed in the opposite order they are created.
    // If this object's d'tor needs to run last, it has to be created first.
    delay_post_msg dpm{ this };

    CWeekendMeetingDlg dlgPublicTalk(this);

    // ...

    if (some_condition)
    {
        dpm.set_active();
    }

    // ...

    // If active, the d'tor of dpm posts the message just before leaving this function.
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a go. I have just updated my question which enhanced code / observation.

Comment: I had to make a tweak here `if (active_) w_->PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, ID_FILE_PUBLIC_TALK, 0);`. I added the `_`.

Comment: Indeed, an incomplete conversion to my personal coding style, that marks `private` class members with a trailing `_`. It has been fixed now.